# Unable to get helper text to work properly with Yup validation and masking in MUI TextField with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup, masking

I am trying to implement masking in an `@mui/material` TextField with `react-hook-form` but having trouble with the helper text to function properly. It works fine with all the other TextField inputs.

**Expected behavior**:
When the user clicks on submit and `Yup` validates the form with specified schema, the helper text shows error messages for invalid input data. The error message automatically disappears afterwards when the user types proper input value which gets validated as the user types.

**Problem statement**:
This is working for the email field, but not for the masked cell phone TextField. The error message never actually disappears and the value does not get validated once the helper text appears and the error gets generated for the first time after an on submit event is invoked.

Here's the Yup Schema:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email(),
  cellPhone: Yup.number()
    .min(10, "Cell phone must have 10 digits at least")
    .max(12, "Cell phone must have 12 digits at max")
    .required("Cell phone is required")
    .typeError("Cell phone is required")
});
```

I tried two approaches. The first approach includes a custom component which I created using `react-input-mask` for masking and Controller from `react-hook-form` for a controlled MUI TextField:

```
<Controller
  name="cellPhone"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <InputMask mask="+99-999-9999999" value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {(inputProps) => (
        <TextField
          {...inputProps}
          fullWidth
          label="Cell phone"
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message}
        />
      )}
    </InputMask>
  )}
/>;
```

The second approach included an MUI-based component available on npm, called `material-ui-phone-number`:

```
<Controller
  name="cellPhone"
  control={control}
  render={({ name, onBlur, onChange, value, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <MuiPhoneNumber
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onBlur={onBlur}
      onChange={onChange}
      defaultCountry="us"
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      label="Cell phone"
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      error={!!error}
      helperText={error?.message}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

I got the same result from both approaches and haven't been able to find the correct answer or to generate the expected outcome. Any help in resolving this is much appreciated, thanks a bunch!

I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the earlier answers and solutions provided by **Arjun**, I was able to implement international masking with `Yup` validation in `react-hook-form` with MUI.

Here's how I set up my Yup schema:

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  cellPhone: Yup.string()
    .required("Cell phone is required")
    .test("isValidMobile", "Cell phone is invalid", (val) => {
      // do your validation - return false to show errors
      // console.log("yup value", val);
      if (!val) {
        return false;
      }
      if (val) {
        if (isMobilePhone(val, "any", { strictMode: true })) {
          return true;
        }
        // below fixes validation for countries with 11+ digit phone numbers,
        // i.e. Pakistan, India, UAE, etc.
        const num = val.replace(/\D/g, "");
        if (num.length >= 12 && num.length <= 15) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }),
});
```

You would need these two packages as well:

```
import MuiPhoneNumber from "material-ui-phone-number-2";
import validator from "validator";
```

Destructure the `isMobilePhone` function from the `validator` package to use it during Yup validation:

```
const { isMobilePhone } = validator;
```

Create a controlled MUI TextField with `react-hook-form` `Controller` and `material-ui-phone-number-2` like this:

```
<Controller
  name="cellPhone"
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <MuiPhoneNumber
      onChange={onChange}
      defaultCountry="us"
      style={{ width: "100%" }}
      label="Cell phone"
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      error={!!error}
      helperText={error?.message}
    />
  )}
/>;
```

Special thanks to **Arjun** who came up with the earlier answers that lead to this solution.

Here's the [updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hooks-8zsgbb?file=/src/pages/InternationalMasking.js) for documented code and some advanced options (like detecting location from timezone to set default country in the phone number field).

Answer (score 1):

This works with your first approach.

Have your yup schema as

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email(),
  cellPhone: Yup.string()
    .required("Cell phone is required")
    .matches(
      /^(\+\d{1,2}-)?\(?\d{3}\)?[-]\d{7}$/,
      "Cell phone must have 12 digits at max"
    )
  });
```

Since you have masked data + and - symbols will be in your value. So cellPhone is not a number field according to Yup. You can see this if you remove .typeError() in your schema,

So, using regexp you can validate your phone number.

Comment: Mann.. I have no words to express my gratitude. THANK YOU!! You don't know how many more hours of grinding you have saved me from. :) I had this task on the backburner since I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get the second approach to work as well? Or what would be the best way to mask the phone input field so that it could accomodate international numbers which might have country codes and phone numbers of variable lengths?

Comment: If you just want the * symbol change your label like `label="Email *"`

Comment: I was able to add the asterisks by adding `required` attribute in `TextField` and adding `noValidate` attribute in `form` element to disable HTML5 validation.

Comment: What would be the regex in Yup if I was masking like this? `+92 (222) 222-2222`. Sorry I keep asking you.  Is there a way to generate regex? I changed the masking in the first approach slightly to match the international format and now it's not being validated. You can see the changes in codesandbox.

Comment: The regex would be : `/^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?(\(?\d{3}\)\s)?\d{3}[-]\d{4}$/` . You can learn & test regex symbols in this website `https://regexr.com/` . This regex might not be a best solution i am suggesting a beginner level solution.

Answer (score 1):

For your second approach, do the changes below

```
    <Controller
        name="cellPhone"
        control={control}
        render={({
          field,
          fieldState: { error }
        }) => (
          <MuiPhoneNumber
            {...field}
            onChange={(value,{name,countryCode,dialCode},...rest)=>{
              console.log("onchange",value,name,countryCode,dialCode)
              field.onChange(value)
            }}
            defaultCountry={"us"}
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            label="Cell phone"
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            error={!!error}
            helperText={error?.message}
          />
        )}
      />
```

Yup schema would be,

```
const Schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().required("Email is required").email(),
  cellPhone: Yup.string()
    .required("Cell phone is required")
    .test('isValidMobile', 'Error message', (val) => {
      console.log("yup value",val)
      //do your validation - return false to show error
      return true;
    })
});
```

for validating you can use this npm package

[validator npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

it has a function `isMobilePhone()`

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestion and to point me in the right direction. I have added validation for international phone numbers as well. For some reason, `Yup` or `material-ui-phone-number` were giving errors on phone numbers with more than 11 digits (e.g. Pakistan and India) and updating to `material-ui-phone-number-2` didn't fix it. I was able to fix that with a simple condition, and added a script to automatically detect user location based on his timezone to pre-populate country code in phone number field.